# JQuery / Javascript Show Hide multiple Content using one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a requirement like this,

```
<p id="admore">Add More</p>
<span id="qulification1">
       Qulification 1<input type="text" name="qulification[]"/>
</span>
<br/>
<span id="qulification2" style="display: none">
    Qulification 2<input type="text" name="qulification[]"/>
    <span id="remove2">remove</span>
</span>
<br/>
<span id="qulification3" style="display: none">
    Qulification 3 <input type="text" name="qulification[]"/>
    <span id="remove3">remove</span>
</span>
```

**qulification2 and qulification3 span default keep hide, when click  one time on  "Add More" btn, it shows qulification2. next click shows qulification3. 
How to do it?**

I have done it using two Add More button. but it is not good way,

```
<p id="admore2">Add More</p>
<p id="admore3">Add More</p>

$('#addmore2').click(function() {
    $('#qulification2').show();
});

$('#addmore3').click(function() {
    $('#qulification3').show();
});
```

Comment: what about 3rd click ? 4 th and so on ?? is there any conditions for that ?

Comment: where is your addmore button  ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV only two additional boxes available, one click get 1st second click gets 2nd, extra click do nothing

Comment: then simply use one flag variable and set its value 1 in first click then write a conditional statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with class selectors, this way
on each click one more appears of those spans:

css: `.invisible { display: none; }`

html: on every span, should be an extra class for grouping and another for invisibility:

`<span id="qulification1" class="q invisible">`

js:

`$('#addmore').click( function() {
  $('span.q.invisible').first().removeClass('invisible');
} );`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do :

```
var counter = 0;

$('#addmore2').click(function() {
    if (count === 0) {
        $('#qulification2').show();
    } else if (count == 1) {
        $('#qulification3').show();
    }
    count++;
});
```

Comment: It has to be done after the second click. Sorry, I didn't mean to downvote

Comment: Closer to what they wants, but  want to be able to show the second part of the content on the second click, so you would have to have an else-if to be able to perform that operation. (That's just what I take from the description)

Comment: all we have to give a direction. Its not necessary to write complete solution. this is really an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are many way to solve the problem you are encountering. About the most simple way to solve this issue is to add a counter to your program which will count how many times you have pressed the button. If you want to only be able to show the content and not hide it again, you can use the following code:

```
var count = 0;

$('#addmore2').click(function() {
    if (count == 0) {
        $('#qulification2').show();
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
        $('#qulification3').show();
    }
    count++;
});
```

However, there may be a better approach to your problem. If you wish to be able to show the content and then be able to hide it once it is all on the screen, you can use the following code:

```
var count = 1;

$('#addmore2').click(function() {
    if (count == 1) {
        $('#qulification2').show();
    }
    else if (count == 2) {
        $('#qulification3').show();
    }
    else if (count == 3) {
        $('#qulification2').hide();
        $('#qulification3').hide();
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the visibility of the spans and show the first one hidden:

```
$('#addmore').click(function() {
    if ( $('#qulification2').css('display') == 'none' )                                     
          $('#qulification2').show();
   else if ( $('#qulification3').css('display') == 'none' )                                     
          $('#qulification3').show();});
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really should do is pragmatically insert another node after user click "Add" button.

Give your whole thing a container, just append to it. For example,

```
 $("#AddButton").click(
function()
{
$("#Container").append("<span>your item stuff</span>");
}

);
```